# Twitter API wss to monitor dedicated users followings

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Can anybody suggests is there within Twitter API an web socket endpoint to monitor
an user (users) followings (sure continuously, since wss) like their streaming API without need their subscription (like Twitter [Account Activity API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api))?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API, no. Twitter also has no websocket APIs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.It's offtop, but what about their streaming API? it's similar with wss API, isn't it?

Comment: there is no streaming API that streams new followers.

Comment: Can you please clarify? I know API endpoint to get an twitter user followings list. But what about to get such info immediately after somebody catch new friend (i.e. not followers but followings)